# How to highlight custom keywords in Ace Editor in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ace-editor

I'm trying to highlight a couple of keywords that are present in this.$rules . However I'm not able to get the final output . Can you please tell me what I'm missing here?

This is what I have tried inside an Angular component

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-itijpu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
import {
 AfterViewInit,
 Component,
 ElementRef,
 OnInit,
 ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import * as ace from 'ace-builds';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
 @ViewChild('editor') private editor: ElementRef;

 constructor() {}

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   ace.config.set('fontSize', '14px');
   const editor = ace.edit(this.editor.nativeElement);
   const oop = ace.require('ace/lib/oop');
   const TextMode = ace.require('ace/mode/text').Mode;
   const TextHighlightRules = ace.require(
     'ace/mode/text_highlight_rules'
   ).TextHighlightRules;

   const customHighlightRules = function () {
     this.$rules = {
       start: [
         {
           regex: /\b(keyword1|keyword2)\b/,
           token: 'keyword',
         },
       ],
     };
   };

   oop.inherits(customHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

   const Mode = function () {
     this.HighlightRules = customHighlightRules;
   };

   oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

   (function () {
     this.$id = 'ace/mode/custom';
   }.call(Mode.prototype));

   // Set here
   editor.getSession().setMode(new (ace.require('ace/mode/custom').Mode)());
   
   editor.setValue('keyword1 some text keyword2', 1);
 }

 ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting mode simply do

```
editor.session.setMode(new Mode());
```

instead of `.setMode(new (ace.require('ace/mode/custom').Mode)())`.

`ace.require` is not needed if you did not define the module with `ace.define`, and you have the object at hand anyway.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-krfkzr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, and make sure that keyword are listed

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var ace: any; // Import ace library (make sure it's installed and available)

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ace-builds-editor',
  templateUrl: './ace-builds-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ace-builds-editor.component.css']
})
export class AceBuildsEditorComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("editor") private editor: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    ace.config.set("fontSize", "14px");

    // custom highlighting rules
    const customHighlightRules = function () {
      this.$rules = {
        start: [
          {
            regex: /\b(sometext|othertext)\b/,
            token: 'keyword',
          },
        ],
      };
    };
    const oop = ace.require('ace/lib/oop');
    const TextHighlightRules = ace.require('ace/mode/text_highlight_rules').TextHighlightRules;
    oop.inherits(customHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

    const Mode = function () {
      this.HighlightRules = customHighlightRules;
    };
    oop.inherits(Mode, ace.require('ace/mode/text').Mode);

    ace.define('ace/mode/custom', [], function (require, exports, module) {
      exports.Mode = Mode;
    });

    const editor = ace.edit(this.editor.nativeElement);
    editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/custom');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , I'm getting an error - 

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Mode')

Comment: Check edited version

Comment: If error appears still try set like this to ensure that module is loaded: ace.config.loadModule('ace/mode/custom', (module: any) => {      editor.getSession().setMode(new module.Mode());
    });

Comment: I'm still getting the same error . Please check this stackblitz 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-itijpu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Check this function which I showed above

Comment: I tried buddy , it still didn't work , getting different error

Comment: Did you get a chance to check the stackblitz? :)

Comment: check update above

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: Thanks for your efforts , The solution by @a user works .